# Run single instance of application from matlab

Tags: matlab

I am calling a java function from matlab (Start.m), which starts a GUI. I want to make sure that if the user calls Start.m again, while an instance of this application is runnning it should throw a warning.
Can i assign processname to a thread which starts from matlab?
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is single threaded.

What about using a singleton pattern in the GUI constructor to prohibit multiple instances. You may also display a warning message from within the GUI.

Another option is a [global](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/global.html) variable to be set in your `startup.m`.